# Should I begin development in Symfony 1.x or 2.0?

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony1

I want to develop webapps for 2011 & 2012, which version I should use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It also depends on your patience with software that is still in development. The website states:

> Be warned that Symfony 2.0 is not stable yet; use it with caution (current version is Beta 5).

This means that things are still under development that breaks compatibility with earlier versions. See: http://symfony.com/download . If you have the stomach for it, go for it, it's a rich and powerful framework. If you need to have things finished yesterday, it's probably better to stick with SF1.4.

On the other hand, the support for sf1.4 will end in November 2012, this might also be something to take into consideration.

Comment: Uh, generally speaking, betas shouldn't introduce anything that breaks compatibility - they exist to uncover bugs in existing functionality. Introducing new changes, that would be in the alphas and nightlies of a new version; however, with marketing slapping the "beta" label to anything left and right, like it's just a cute image to hang over your app's logo, this no longer seems like a useful distinction.

Comment: I agree, and know what beta means. But also: have you checked the latest release notes? There are still breaking changes. Not as bad as before, and I suppose they will go stable soon.

Comment: I'm not denying that. So much for the "nightly build, alpha, beta, RC, final" cycle - now everything is either a beta or the final version :( Pity, it was a somewhat useful nomenclature.

Comment: I suppose, but they started from scratch with SF2, I suppose now is the last moment they might still change these 'bugs' or refactors. A bit of insight on the development process is given by fabien potencier: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/47/pragmatism-over-theory-protected-vs-private

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have an existing codebase that mandates a particular version then 2.0 is probably better since it has a richer and more advanced API.

[The official announcement of improvements in Symfony2](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-getting-easier)

Answer (score 1):

This has been Q&A'd many times.

2.0 is not even in the RC phase yet - keep that in mind.
And 1.4 will be supported for the next few years.

If your apps not gonna be "big", it'd do them in 1.4, and then maybe change to 2.0 if you REALLY need it.

Otherwise you have to wait until 2.0 goes stable, which may take from 1 to a few months.

Comment: 1.4 will be supported till the end of 2012. However this might change as 2.0 was supposed to be finalised in March 2011 which would have allowed 21 months to do a rewrite, but as 2 is delayed that time period i (obviously) being eroded

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 2.0 will be in RC phase in next week, and will be officially released in july this year, so i think its very close to be stable :)